# How to Refactor an Async Function out of a React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a straightforward react component that looks so in `AllWords.js` :

```
import React, {  useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import consts from '../../constants/Constants.js';

function AllWords() {
  const [words, setWords] = useState([]);

  async function fetchData(){
    
    const response= await fetch(consts.FETCH_URL);
    const data = await (response.json());
    setWords(data);
  };

  // API:  useEffect( () => { . . . return cleanup; },[var_n_whose_change_triggers_useEffect . . .] );

  useEffect(() => {fetchData()}, [] );

    return (
    <>
    {
      words.map(w=> <div>{w.word}</div>)
    }
    </>
  );
}

export default AllWords;
```

I would like to refactor the `fetchData()` method out of the component into another file (basically a separate `.js` file that holds the fetch call).

What I would like is to have created a file titled `FetchAllWords.js` under `src/actions/` & then import it. & use that.

I have several questions :

1. do I need to set the `state` in the `FetchAllWords.js` and then `useSelector` to extract the state in `AllWords.js`?
2. in `FetchAllWords.js` do I need to `usedispatch` to dispatch a method call setting the `state`? I would like to just `setState` in  `FetchAllWords.js` and then extract it in `AllWords.js`. This is what I have so far:

```
import consts from '../constants/Constants.js';
import {  useState } from 'react';


async function FetchAllWords(){
    const [words, setWords] = useState([]);
  
        const response= await fetch(consts.FETCH_URL);
        const data = await (response.json());
        setWords(data);
    
}
 

export default FetchAllWords;
```

I am unsure how to import this and use it in `AllWords.js`. I am using the following statement :
`import wordList from '../../actions/FetchAllWords';`

Then I am trying to use `wordList` as a handle to the file `'../../actions/FetchAllWords.js'` & attempting to access the `async function` `FetchAllWords` so `wordList.FetchAllWords()`;

Firstly , the editor (VSCode) won't let me see the function despite the import call.

Secondly I am getting an error (something like) :
`TypeError: _actions_FetchAllWords_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.default.FetchAllWords is not a function`

Any insight or help would be appreciated since rather uneasy with JS & React.
The github repo is : https://github.com/mrarthurwhite/hooks-p5-react-redux

*EDIT*: As per David's suggestions :

So `AllWords.js` React component is :

```
import React, {  useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import wordList from '../../services/Fetch.js';
function AllWords() {
  const [words, setWords] = useState([]);

  function fetchData(){
    
    wordList.fetchAllWords().then(
      data =>  setWords(data)
    );
  };

  // API:  useEffect( () => { . . . return cleanup; },[var_n_whose_change_triggers_useEffect . . .] );
  useEffect(() => {fetchData()}, [] );

    return (
    <>
    {
      words.map(w=> <div>{w.word}</div>)
    }
    </>
  );
}

export default AllWords;
```

And `Fetch.js` is :

```
import consts from '../constants/Constants.js';

class Fetch { 

async fetchAllWords(){
        const response= await fetch(consts.FETCH_URL);
        const data = await (response.json());
        return data;
}
 
       
}
export default Fetch;
```

Answer (score 1):

No, don't worry about state in the external file.  Just focus on the one thing it should do, perform the AJAX operation.  At its simplest it's just a function, something like:

```
import consts from '../../constants/Constants.js';

const fetchAllWords = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(consts.FETCH_URL);
    const data = await (response.json());
    return data;
}

export default fetchAllWords;
```

You can even make it a class which contains this function, if you plan on adding other service operations as well.  (Fetch specific word?  Find word?  etc.)  The point is that this does just one thing, provide data.  Let the React components handle React state.

Within the component you'd just use that to get your data.  Something like:

```
import React, {  useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import fetchAllWords from '../../services/FetchAllWords.js';

function AllWords() {
  const [words, setWords] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchAllWords().then(w => setWords(w));
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
    {
      words.map(w=> <div>{w.word}</div>)
    }
    </>
  );
}

export default AllWords;
```

Overall it's a matter of separating concerns.  The service performs the AJAX operation and returns the meaningful data, internally concerned with things like JSON deserialization and whatnot.  The React component maintains the state and renders the output, internally concerned with updating state after `useEffect` runs and whatnot.

Comment: thank you so much, that is what I was trying to do. I did as you requested but I still cannot seem to import it. The error I am getting is the same : `×
TypeError: _services_Fetch_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.default.fetchAllWords is not a function...`

This is just the same but with the names changed. I made the fetching as part of a class & other changes (please see github since I cannot put all the code here). @David

Comment: @ArthurW: Can you update the question with the two files?  Specifically what the separate files creates and exports, and how the component imports and uses it?

Comment: I have done that (included the changes in the question) as per your kind request. However the github repo should have the latest files too. @David

Comment: @ArthurW: Ah, like you said it’s a class now.  I think it’s just that you’re calling the function on the class itself.  You can make the function static, or create an instance of the class and call the function from that instance.